# problem with CS50 reverse! audio file is reversed and seems fine to me, however final check reverse.c reverses ascending scale does not tick off

Tags: c, cs50, wav

here is my code, audio file seems perfectly fine and sounds reversed only thing that doesnt check off is the final tick on cs50! please can someone help me out thanks in advance!

:( reverse.c reverses ascending scale
file is not reversed as specified

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "wav.h"

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1



    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("enter wav files");
        return 1;
    }
    else if(strstr(argv[1], ".wav") != NULL && strstr(argv[2], ".wav") != NULL)
    {
        ;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }


    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2

    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(input == NULL)
    {
        printf("no file was opened");
        return 1;
    }


    // Read header
    // TODO #3

    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, input);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4

    if(check_format(header) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6

    fwrite(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER),1, output);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7

    int size = get_block_size(header);

    int audio_size = header.subchunk2Size / size;



    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8


    BYTE *buffer = malloc(size);

    fseek(input, size, SEEK_END);


    while(ftell(input) - size >= sizeof(header))
    {
        if(fseek(input, -2 * size, SEEK_CUR))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        fread(buffer, size, 1, input);
        fwrite(buffer, size, 1, output);

    }

}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4

    BYTE format[] = {'W','A','V','E'};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(header.format[i] != format[i])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    return 1;
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    int bytes = 0;

    bytes += (header.bitsPerSample / 8) * header.numChannels;

    return (bytes);
}
```

tried changing fseek values and stuff but nothing seems to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `fseek` inside your `while` loop skips the first record to read.

You should begin by seeking the first record, before the loop, and I suggest this rearrangement (not tested):

```
fseek(input, -size, SEEK_END);              // align with final record
while(ftell(input) >= sizeof(header))       // changed this condition
{
    fread(buffer, size, 1, input);
    fwrite(buffer, size, 1, output);
    if(fseek(input, -2 * size, SEEK_CUR))   // align with next record
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

To be portable the files should be opened in binary mode `"rb"` or `"wb"` – on Windows that will be essential. And to be robust, check that all the file function calls return the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to put the pointer in the end of the file and move backwards.

```
fseek(input, -size, SEEK_END);
```

the code is below the BYTE array line.